winget configure configuration.dsc.yaml - to set windows group membership
I have the following configuration.dsc.yaml file:
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://aka.ms/configuration-dsc-schema/0.2
properties:
  assertions:
    - resource: Microsoft.Windows.Developer/OsVersion
      directives:
        description: Verify min OS version requirement
        allowPrerelease: true
      settings:
        MinVersion: '10.0.19045'
  resources:
    - resource: Microsoft.WinGet.DSC/WinGetPackage
      id: Docker
      directives:
        description: Install Docker
        allowPrerelease: true
      settings:
        id: Docker.DockerDesktop
        source: winget
  configurationVersion: 0.2.0

Which will install docker when I run:
winget configure configuration.dsc.yaml 

However because my domain user is not an administrator on my machine I need to add my user to the docker-users group. I can do that from a PowerShell command prompt with this:
net localgroup docker-users $ENV:USERDOMAIN\$ENV:USERNAME /add

I have found the following documentation for DSC GroupSet Resource:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/reference/resources/windows/groupsetresource?view=dsc-1.1
Is it possible to use this to configure adding users to a group in a .dsc.yaml file?

It looks like only the resources here: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-dsc/tree/main/resources are available to WinGet

The following is a way of doing it using PSDscResources/Script that will work in windows 11 with Sudo for Windows enabled.
For windows 10 replace the sudo SetScript with:
$sh = new-object -com 'Shell.Application' ; $sh.ShellExecute('powershell', "-Command net localgroup docker-users $ENV:USERDOMAIN\$ENV:USERNAME /add", '', 'runas')

Docker.dsc.yaml:
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://aka.ms/configuration-dsc-schema/0.2
properties:
  assertions:
    - resource: Microsoft.Windows.Developer/OsVersion
      directives:
        description: Verify min OS version requirement
        allowPrerelease: true
      settings:
        MinVersion: '10.0.19045'
    - resource: PSDscResources/Script
      id: domainuser
      directives:
        description: Checks that the user is running this as their Domain user. 
      settings:
        GetScript: |
          return ($ENV:USERDOMAIN -ne $ENV:COMPUTERNAME)
        SetScript: |
          return false
        TestScript: |
          return ($ENV:USERDOMAIN -ne $ENV:COMPUTERNAME)
  resources:
    - resource: PSDscResources/Script
      id: DockerUsers
      dependsOn:
      - domainuser
      directives:
        description: Add user to docker-users group so that Docker can run as non-admin
      settings:
        GetScript: |
          return (net localgroup docker-users | Select-String "$ENV:USERNAME" -SimpleMatch -Quiet)
        SetScript: 
          sudo net localgroup docker-users $ENV:USERDOMAIN\$ENV:USERNAME /add
        TestScript: |
          return (net localgroup docker-users | Select-String "$ENV:USERNAME" -SimpleMatch -Quiet)
    - resource: Microsoft.WinGet.DSC/WinGetPackage
      id: Docker
      dependsOn:
      - DockerUsers
      directives:
        description: Install Docker
        allowPrerelease: true
      settings:
        id: Docker.DockerDesktop
        source: winget
configurationVersion: 0.2.0

